# How to code concurrency (creating threads) on Application server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency

I know there are some sources in the web for this topic, but it is confusing me that every application server seems to have its own measurement of how to handle concurrency and offering there own thread pools.

Is it a No-Go to create Threads on it's own on an application server? (e.g. new Thread()...) 
If yes, does there a common approach exist independently of the used application server?

Answer (score 0):

The EJB specification assigns to the EJB container the responsibility for managing threads.

Allowing enterprise bean instances to create and manage threads would interfere with the container's ability to control its components' lifecycle. **Thread management is not a business function, it is an implementation detail, and is typically complicated and platform-specific.**

Letting the container manage threads relieves the enterprise bean developer of dealing with threading issues. Multithreaded applications are still possible, but control of multithreading is located in the container, not in the enterprise bean.

source: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/qanda/ejb_tier/restrictions.html#threads

Answer (score 0):

EJB 3.1 introduces `@Asynchronous` annotation that lets you run some code in separate thread, managed by container. [Howto here.](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2010/03/simple-asynchronous-methods-in-ejb-31.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should not create your own threads when you are in an EJB. Indeed, EJB 3.1 introduces @Asynchronous annotation for this purpose. Previous versions of WebSphere and WebLogic implement WorkManager, another ad-hoc standard (the JSR 237 for making it a standard was abandoned in the end) for worker threads that can be launched from an EJB.